# Does the volume change when the reactions occur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, concentration

I have this reaction (all substances are gaseous):

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{A + 4.5 B &→ C + 2 D + 2 E}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{C + 7.5 B &→ 8 D + 2 E}\tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

Does the volume change when the reactions has occurred?
Because if so, the concentration changes too, right?

Comment: The volume changes can only be predicted if at least one of the substances A, B, C, D and E is gaseous. If the substances are not gaseous, no predictions can be made.

Comment: Just edited it(all substances are gaseous)

Comment: I don't understand why sometimes questions that classify as homework (of course they might even be genuine users Q) get answered. OP poses a trivial question without attempts/discussion at all.

Comment: @Alchimista To poorly paraphrase Michael Caine, "...some men just want to watch the world learn".

Answer (score 3):

A volume change from a reaction occurs if the difference in mole of gases does not equal to $0$

In order to find the answer for your question, we will have to add both reactions together, resulting in:
$$\ce{A + 4.5 B + C + 7.5 B -> C + 2 D + 2 E + 8 D + 2E}$$
We can shorten the reaction by adding up all duplicates and removing both $\ce{C}$ from each side, resulting in:
$$\ce{A + 12 B -> 10 D + 4E}$$
Now if we calculate the difference in mole gasses we get:
$$\Delta n = \pu{(10 + 4)mol} - \pu{(1 + 12)mol} = \pu{1 mol}$$
Based on the positiv difference in mole of gasses we can say that the reaction will change in volume, that is it will expand.